# Find specific value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

There is an array:

```
$arr = array(
        'AA' => 90,
        'AB' => 150,
        'BC' => 100,
        'CD' => 60
);
```

and a string:

```
$val = 'CD'
```

Is there any quick way (without FOR loop) to define the numeric value corresponding to `$val`? In this example the result must be 60.

Comment: are you asking for `$arr[$val]`?

Comment: `$value = isset($arr[$val]) ? $arr[$val] : null` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You literally just need `$arr[$val]`.

`echo $arr[$val];` will output 60.

Answer (score 2):

```
$value = @$arr[$val];
```

it's all you need